# How to extract 4 words before each word of a given list in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a table with a column containing text (the column name is 'Text'). There are some acronyms in brackets, so I would like to extract them along with the five words appearing before them.

I have already extracted the rows that contain all the acronyms of my list using the like operator:

```
select Text from table 
where Text like '(NASA)'
or Text like '(NBA)'
```

In stead of getting an output of the whole text in each row:

Text

He works for the  National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA).

He played basketball for the National Basketball Association (NBA) from 2000 to 2002.

I would like to get the  output of two columns one for the acronym and another for the meaning of the acronym (showing the five words prior to the acronym):

```
Acronym      Meaning
(NASA)       National Aeronautics and Space Administration
(NBA)        for the National Basketball Association
```

Answer (score 0):

Without actually seeing your data, I will assume that all the acronyms follow the same pattern but you should be able to adapt the code with the correct logic if your strings are structured differently. In this case '(Acronym) meaning' is the structure which I'm going to work with.

```
select '(NASA) National Aeronautics and Space Administration' as text
into #temp1
union all
select '(FBI) Federal Bureau of Investigation' as text

select SUBSTRING(text,CHARINDEX('(',text)+1 ,CHARINDEX(')',text)-CHARINDEX('(',text)-1)  as Acronym,
SUBSTRING(text,CHARINDEX(')',text)+2 ,len(text)-CHARINDEX(')',text)+1)  as meaning
from #temp1
```

This code subsets the original string by using character positions in the string between the brackets for the acronym and then character positions starting after closed brackets for the meanings.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Could I kindly ask your help about how could I extract only the relevant information for creating #temp1, please? For instance, 'National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA)'  is only a small part of a larger text. How could I extract only that part (following the logic: (NASA) and five words before) in order to be able to create the two columns. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @A.S which DBMS product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server